# Use Fermat's Little Theorem to prove that $x^{13} \equiv x \mod 70$ for any $x$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Use Fermat's Little Theorem to prove that $x^{13} \equiv x \mod 70$ for any $x$. Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know Fermat's Little Theorem?

Comment: yes, I know it says $x^p \equiv x \mod p$ for any prime $p$. So I know $ x^{13} \equiv x \mod 13$. But how can I proceed?

Comment: So $ x^{71} \equiv x \mod 71$. But why does that help?

Comment: Hint: the congruence is true modulo $70$ if and only if it is true modulo $2$ and modulo $5$ and modulo $7$.

Comment: as David said, your prime factors of 70 are 2,5,and 7... so by the iff....

Comment: We show for example that $x^{13}\equiv x\pmod{5}$. If $x$ is not divisible by $5$, then $x^{12}=(x^4)^3\equiv 1\pmod{5}$, and therefore $x^{13}\equiv x\pmod{5}$. If $x$ is divisible by $5$, then $x^{13}\equiv x\pmod{5}$ holds trivially.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it!

Comment: You are welcome. The argument generalizes. Let $p_1,\dots,p_k$ be **distinct** primes, and let $m=p_1p_2\cdots p_k$. If $p_i-1$ divides $n-1$ for all $i$, then $x^n\equiv x\pmod{m}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply the obvious extension of the theorem below to $\,3\,$ primes.  In your case we have $\,k=1,\,$ and $\phi=12\,$ is a common multiple of $\phi(2)=1,\,\ \phi(5)=4,\,\ \phi(7)=6.$

**Theorem** $\ \ \ n^{\large k+\phi}\equiv n^{\large k}\pmod{p^i q^j}\ \ $ assuming that $ \ \color{#0a0}{\phi(p^i),\phi(q^j)\mid \phi},\, $  $\, i,j \le k,\,\ p\ne q.\ \ \ $

**Proof** $\ \ p\nmid n\,\Rightarrow\, {\rm mod\ }p^i\!:\  n^{ \phi}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, n^{k + \phi}\equiv n^k,\, $ by $\  n^{\Large \color{#0a0}\phi} = (n^{\color{#0a0}{\Large \phi(p^{ i})}})^{\large \color{#0a0}m}\overset{\color{blue}{\rm (E)}}\equiv 1^{\large m}\equiv 1\,$ by [Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) $\!\rm\color{blue}{(E)}$.

$\qquad\quad\ \ \color{#c00}{p\mid n}\,\Rightarrow\, {\rm mod\ }p^i\!:\  n^k\equiv 0\,\equiv\, n^{k + \phi}\ $ by $\ n^k = n^{k-i} \color{#c00}n^i = n^{k-i} (\color{#c00}{mp})^i$ and $\,k\ge i.$

So $\ p^i\mid n^{k+\phi}\!-n^k.\,$ By symmetry $\,q^j$ divides it too, so their lcm $ = p^iq^j\,$ divides it too. $\ $ **QED**

**Remark** $\ $ Obviously the proof immediately extends to an arbitrary number of primes. This leads the way to [Carmichael's Lambda function,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) a generalization of [Euler's phi function.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!